# Como passar o projeto do Netbeans para um arquivo .jar?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Acabei de fazer um projeto no Netbeans e gostaria de transforma-lo em um *app* para executar no PC, por isso quero transforma-lo em .jar. Como fazer isso?

Comment: É só exportar o jar.

Comment: Não sei exportar o jar

Comment: F11 ou vai em `Run -> Build project`

Comment: Quando vou em "exportar projeto", só aparece a opção para ZIP

Comment: Você tentou o que eu falei no ultimo comentário?

Comment: Tentei, mas nada acontece, se aconteceu não sei onde ele construiu o projeto

Comment: Na pasta DIST dentro do seu projeto

Comment: Onde acho a pasta DIST

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No netbeans, basta apertar <kbd>F11</kbd> com o projeto selecionado ou clicar com o botão direito sobre o projeto desejado, e clicar em `Build` ou  `Clean and Bluid`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O netbeans irá criar um arquivo `jar` dentro de uma subpasta no diretório do seu projeto chamada `dist`.

Comment: Obrigado diegofm, desculpe a burrice, comecei a usar o netbeans hoje.

Comment: @GuilhermePassos sem problemas :)

Comment: @GuilhermePassos se a resposta lhe ajudou, você pode marcá-la como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda. Veja como o site funciona em [tour]

Comment: Eu já vou aceita-la, só estou esperando o tempo mínimo para isso

Comment: eu consegui transformar em .jar, mas ele n ta executando, tem alguma sugestão do que fazer?

Comment: @GuilhermePassos ai é outro problema, e bem complicado de sugerir algo porque pode ter N causas. Tente executar o jar via linha de comando e ver se aparece erros. Abre uma janela do prompt na pasta dist e digita: `java -jar arquivoJar.jar`