# Aplicação demora na troca entre telas

Tags: java, swing

Quando vou mudar de tela, sempre tem um demorinha de uma tela para outra e isso é chato. Você vê claramente que uma tela fecha para abrir outra. sabe aquele símbolo do java que fica quando se abre uma aplicação?

Então, quando abro uma tela ele aparece, quando abro outra, ele some e aparece.

O que eu queria na verdade é que a transição entre telas não fosse "perceptível".

Estou usando o método dispose() para fechar uma tela e abrir outra, não afirmo com certeza, mas eu acho que com o setVisible(false) fica da mesma forma.

Existe solução para isso?

```
package visao;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TelaInicialUm extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton btnOutraTela;

public TelaInicialUm() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnOutraTela = new JButton("outra tela");
    btnOutraTela.setBounds(135, 67, 148, 93);
    contentPane.add(btnOutraTela);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public JButton getBtnOutraTela() {
    return btnOutraTela;
}

}
```

package visao;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class TelaDois extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JButton btnTelaTres;

public TelaDois() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnTelaTres = new JButton("Tela tres");
    btnTelaTres.setBounds(200, 136, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnTelaTres);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

public JButton getBtnTelaTres() {
    return btnTelaTres;
}
}
```

package controle;

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import visao.TelaDois;
import visao.TelaInicialUm;

public class ControleTelaInicialUm implements ActionListener{

private TelaInicialUm tiu;

public ControleTelaInicialUm(TelaInicialUm tiu) {

    this.tiu = tiu;     
    this.tiu.getBtnOutraTela().addActionListener(this);

    tiu.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==tiu.getBtnOutraTela()){
        this.tiu.dispose();
        new ControleTelaDois(new TelaDois());
    }
}
}
```

package controle;

```
import visao.TelaDois;

public class ControleTelaDois {

private TelaDois td;
public ControleTelaDois(TelaDois td) {
    this.td = td;

    td.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

package controle;

```
import visao.TelaInicialUm;

public class MainTelas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ControleTelaInicialUm(new TelaInicialUm());
}
}
```

Comment: Precisa fechar uma janela pra abrir a outra? Geralmente aplicações desktop têm múltiplas janelas.

Comment: fechar, fechar não! preciso esconder uma janela para aparecer outra

Comment: Uma janela modal não resolve?

Comment: eu não sei o que é uma janela modal. a aplicação está toda feita, mudaria muita coisa, meu código está em mvc

Comment: Se sua aplicação está em MVC, então não faz diferença que tipo de visualização escolhe, certo? Modal é uma janela que fica por cima da outra, impedindo a interação com a de baixo.

Comment: Por favor, apresente um **[mcve]** para que possamos simular o problema. Sem ver, fica complicado sugerir algo.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo, pena que não vai da tanto pra ver essa troca de uma para outra, pq a tela não tem muita imagem, então a troca fica suave. mas a minha aplicação é construida nesse modelo aí, a diferença é que tem muitos componentes na tela

Comment: Gifs mostrando a transição são apreciados

Comment: não sei fazer! mas imagina que quando fecho uma tela, em vez da outra já aparecer rapidamente, vc percebe claramente que a anterior fechou e evc fica esperando que a outra abra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testei o código aqui e este problema não ocorreu, como pode ser visto no gif:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que você não deveria se preocupar com isso, qual o problema de uma tela ser vista sendo fechada enquanto outra está sendo aberta? Isso é puramente visual e estético, e não faz sentido(ao menos para mim) se preocupar com isso. Ainda mais que, provavelmente, a causa dessa suposta "lag" é o computador.

Além do mais, não vejo como isso pode de forma alguma atrapalhar algo em qualquer aplicação java-swing, a não ser que a causa seja a execução de algum método, o que pelo menos lendo os códigos e executando-os, não foi detectado nada de tão complexo.

A única coisa que posso sugerir sem fugir do escopo do site é que reinstale ou atualize sua JDK e recompile sua aplicação, se continuar o suposto problema, crie um jar e tente rodar diretamente dele, sem envolver IDE nisso. Se mesmo assim continuar, teste o jar em outro computador. [Neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210026/28595) mostra como criar um jar no Netbeans e [neste outro link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/205794/28595) mostra como fazer o procedimento no Eclipse.

E uma dica final é usar [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) ao invés de um monte de JFrames, pois você pode acabar se perdendo entre eles na hora de fazer alguma troca de informação entre as janelas. Segue alguns links com vários exemplos de como criar `JDialogs`:

- [Como chamar uma JFrame de outra JFrame com classes diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118192/28595)
- [Abrir várias janelas da mesma aplicação sem acumular icones na barra de tarefas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142609/28595)
- [Definir quais JFrames ficarão com foco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/126351/28595)

E quando se está programando em java-swing, sempre deve-se iniciar a tela dentro da [Event-Dispatch-Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/event-dispatch-thread/info), pois swing não é *Thread-Safe*, e toda a GUI precisa iniciar dentro desta unica Thread. [Nesta resposta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SruVb.gif) explica melhor o motivo para isto e eventuais problemas que podem ocorrer. [Esta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193456/28595) mostra algumas maneiras de como iniciar a aplicação dentro desta Thread.

Comment: a minha aplicação está dentro da  Event-Dispatch-Thread. esse gif que eu te mando, não estou rodando dentro da ide, é a partir do .jar gerado. Vc pode observar que quando eu clico no botão para abrir a segunda tela, aparece a área de trabalho, veja o tempo que demora na imagem da area de trabalho, para aparecer a outra tela, agora imagina isso a aplicação inteira.... isso incomoda demais o usuário.

Comment: @Manuelacarneiro isso não tem nada a ver com java então. É seu sistema operacional ou seu computador e isso é fora do escopo do site. Siga as dicas q dei na resposta e não ligue pra isso, não tem nada de errado nessa lag. No seu código não acontece isso e se acontece só com você, não há nada q possa ser feito. Teste em um computador mais potente para ver se o problema ocorre

Comment: ah certo, eu pensei que poderia existir alguma forma de "melhorar" o meu código.

Comment: @Manuelacarneiro melhorar o que por exemplo? O problema não é nele, é na forma como seu computador tá executando, isso não tem como fazer milagre. Teste em outro Pc, este problema não é na aplicação, seu código está bom.

Comment: mas veja, esse exemplo de código que eu postei, viu coo ele abre rápido, vc não percebe esse lag, mas no gif que eu mandei, da para perceber, pq?

Comment: será que não são as imagens que são pesadas demais?enfim, tou tentando buscar explicações

Comment: @Manuelacarneiro eu já te dei os motivos, não entendo quais outros está procurando. Não é culpa do java ou do seu código. é do seu sistema operacional. A não ser que reclame com a microsoft, não tem nada que tenha a fazer para mudar isso.

Comment: certo. obrigada!